# How are AR devices called that are not dedicated to this task?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Hololens and HTC Vive etc are dedicated Augmented Reality devices. However there are AR applications for smartphones and tablets as well. How are devices called, whose primary purpose is not AR but they still support AR applications? Second class AR devices?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about technology, not English.

Comment: @HotLicks An answer not in english would not help me. But I can see your point. which stackexchange would you recommend?

Comment: [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) would be possible starting places.

Comment: @HotLicks based on their help -> what topics can I ask about here? they do not seem to be appropriate places either... The first is explicitly not about "electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones" and the second is about theory and science not about products...

Comment: Just because my question also contains technology it is still about finding an english word or term. I think this is the most appropriate stackexchange. I looked a bit through single word requests and some also could be argued to fit into other stackexchanges. For example right now one about "space-time magic" is on top, that would fit into the "Science Fiction & Fantasy" stackexchange.

Comment: So, would “***AR-capable***” work?

Comment: AR = Assault rifle.  Accounts receivable.  Aspect ratio.  And 100 others.  Do not assume your readers know such things.

Comment: You appear to be asking about industry-specific jargon.

Comment: _**AR-enabled**_ is a term that you could use. There's no industry-standard classification.

Comment: @Jim Wouldn't that also include devices that are dedicated to AR?

Comment: @IanMacDonald That sounds interesting. I don't need an industry-standard classification, I need a term that communicates the meaning in less than a full sentence.

Comment: @findusl - I’d call those AR devices.  So either AR or AR-capable.

Answer (score 1):

How about **AR-compatible**?

> [**compatible**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/compatible): able to be used with a particular type of computer, machine, device, etc.:
>
> **[compatible](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/compatible.html)**: the ability of one device or program to work with another device or program

So you could say that a particular AR application -- X -- is compatible with a particular non-AR device -- Y. One would say that Y is **X-compatible**, that Y can run X. The compatibility of a non-AR device with a particular AR application would depend on the application and the device. In characterizing a device as compatible with an AR application, it is implicit that the device is itself not an AR device.

**Addendum**: **AR-capable**, as suggested by @Jim and noted by Hellion below, is another good option.

Comment: Alternatively, "AR-capable".

Comment: @Hellion Agree. *AR-capable* is good option. Jim suggested it in one of the comments.

Comment: Why, so he did.  I should expand those more often, I guess.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about... *non-dedicated* AR devices? This makes it clear that the devices can use AR but that’s not their primary purpose. It’s the obvious natural choice, so much so that it practically appears in the text of the question.

[Another example](https://books.google.com/books?id=XM10DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=%22non%20dedicated%22%20ar%20device&source=bl&ots=0oW_lr2ZKU&sig=ACfU3U2ejhJb_zFbBeTCVZgSV4es5e6kiw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk0MO39rbpAhXBY98KHS0UBCsQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22non%20dedicated%22%20ar%20device&f=false):

> There are dedicated platforms such as smart glasses and standalone HMDs as well as non-dedicated platforms such as smartphones and desktop computers.